# Progress updates at end of execution in jframe

Tags: java, jframe, netbeans-7

I have crated one program for progress bar in which I am using sleep(1000) to check whether progress bar is working or not. but I observed that when I am executing the program, progress bar is getting updated at last of execution (not in middle).

Can you guys please tell me where am I wrong here?

```
package com.automation_scripts;
public class NewJFrame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public NewJFrame1() {
        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jProgressBar1 = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton1.setActionCommand(jButton1.getActionCommand());
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                try {
                    jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(123, 123, 123)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 190, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 159, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(16, 16, 16)))
                .addContainerGap(87, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(86, 86, 86)
                .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 52, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(51, 51, 51)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 53, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(58, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) throws InterruptedException {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        jProgressBar1.setValue(10);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        jProgressBar1.setValue(20);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        jProgressBar1.setValue(30);
        Thread.sleep(1000);

    }                                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar jProgressBar1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: I think this is the problem: You are using sleep in jButton1ActionPerformed, which is called by the event listener. This means that when you press the button, your GUI itself goes to sleep, so it doesnt update. Try moving it somewhere else, along with the jProgressBar1.setValue, I suggest the main method. To connect it back to your button press will be more work.

Comment: Actually, I am calling 4-5 function once button is clicked based on some check boxes. So, I will have to call the function inside the jButton1ActionPerformed since I am using button. So I will have to use progress bar in jButton1ActionPerformed itself.

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure what you want. Have you moved the code I mentioned somewhere else? I can't see that you are calling 4-5 functions once the button is pressed. If you have changed your code, please edit your answer here so I can see it. Also please specify exactly what result you want, because I don't understand why you want to update your progress bar with a delay. And if it is just for testing, why dont you remove the delay?